# ConnectionKit app not opening on other Computers

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, frameworks

I created a Mac app that uses [ConnectionKit](https://github.com/karelia/ConnectionKit) to connect to a server using FTP. Today I went to export the file and use it on another computer only to find that the app does not open entirely on a different computer.

On the development computer, the app functions completely, but on another computer, it opens, the icon stops bouncing in the dock, and the name of the app is shown in the menu bar, but the first view controller and window are never opened.

The menu is also not visible. It just shows the app title and nothing else.

I assume that this has to do with ConnectionKit, but I checked the package contents of the exported bundle and ConnectionKit is in there under Frameworks.

Here are the steps I took to include it.

1. I downloaded ConnectionKit using `git clone`
2. I downloaded each git submodule using `git submodule update --recursive --init`
3. I dragged the ConnectionKit.xcodeproj file to my Frameworks directory in the project explorer
4. I added ConnectionKit from the workspace into the "Link Binary with Libraries" section

[image]

5. I added a new "Copy Files" build phase.
6. I changed the destination to "Frameworks"
7. I added the ConnectionKit.framework from the Products of the ConnectionKit.xcodeproj to the copy files phase.

[image]

The build phases tab looks like this:

[image]

This doesn't seem to work. The application just sits there and doesn't launch the app on any computer other than the development computer.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the app in Xcode under the debugger on one of these other computers.  It sounds very likely that you are getting a raise at launch.  Seeing the raise in the debugger would doubtless shed light on the cause, which might or might not even have anything to do with ConnectionKit.  :->  You could also look at the console logs generated by your app, in Console.app (in Applications/Utilities/), but actually getting the raise in the debugger is generally more useful unless the problem is something very obvious.

Comment: It was actually a storyboard issue. I was trying to run an app with storyboards on 10.9; I didn't know that Storyboards were a new feature introduced in 10.10.